# Very confusing UX when dismissing candidate

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Looked over a candidate and realized it wasn't a good fit so I see this screen:

[image]

Clicked the button "**DISMISS Remove from list**" (please remove the happy and sad face, they blend into the buttons too much).  Anyhow clicking this yields this:

[image]

If you're going to change the tab color to red (where it says "NEW Added to consideration"), you should really change the text as well..it's very misleading.  I just dismissed a candidate yet the tab says "**NEW Added to consideration**"???!?!  The changing of the color forces the end user's eyes to focus in on that tab - yet the tab is stating opposite of what I just wanted.

This is very confusing.

Comment: Do me a favor and split this into two questions so we can talk about each independently? The UX of dismissing a candidate is a totally separate issue from providing a feedback loop to candidates. Both worthy of discussion, but they're only kind of related.

Comment: @Laura - Community may downvote me to oblivion with that.  What do you recommend me do file a new question and edit this one to talk about the user experience?  I hate to do that...

Comment: yes, I'm suggesting that you edit this question to deal with one of the two issues currently mentioned in it, and post a new question with the second one.

Comment: @Laura and its okay to post the second one even though I authored the linked question about being in "limbo" ?

Comment: Yes, it's okay to post the second one. The linked question is asking what we're doing, but here you're proposing a specific new feature that's not mentioned in the other thread.

Comment: @Laura - Edited and moved second question.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Jon that it shouldn't say "Added to consideration" when the applicant has just been dismissed from consideration.

Comment: The word "NEW" seems to differ from the terms used for the other stages.  New what?  Would a term like "CONSIDER" or "SCREEN" better describe the first stage?