# When dismissing candidate send this as feedback to candidate

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Currently, employers can "dismiss" a candidate.  However, the candidate has no feedback that their application has been rejected, the rejection and any notes about it are only visible to the employer.

The candidate should receive a notification, such as "Your application to position X has been rejected", or at least be able to check the status of their applications.

Additionally, the employer should be able to send an *optional* message when rejecting.  This would [let the candidate know *why* they didn't get hired](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-pro), if the employer is willing to provide that information.  Some pre-made comments could be available to select as well.

[Originally from this question, but moved here per @Laura.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319675/very-confusing-ux-when-dismissing-candidate-also-force-user-to-enter-a-reason-f)

Comment: Such a constraint would just stop recruiters using SO.

Comment: What does this have to do with the recruiter?  You are providing feedback to someone waiting on a job.  Its called transparency and it is much needed.

Comment: If 1000 candidates apply for a job, who is going to pay for the time spent on explaining to 999 of them why they were rejected?

Comment: @MartinJames - Please see why I mentioned a standard set of radio buttons...as well as optional comments...as well as the ability to MASS SEND.  The limitations you speak of can easily be solved - you know that!  You're also talking about extreme cases, for a single job posting it's not always common to have 1000's of resumes.  Maybe 1000's of resumes pending at a workplace for various positions but certainly not one position.

Comment: Technically yes.  Unfortunately, it's an imposition that those who wish to fill vacancies will not want.  They will always reply with 'a candidate applied who was better suited to the role', (ie. pointless).

Comment: @MartinJames - Maybe but also maybe not.  I tend to favor the latter as times have changed.  I mean let's face it companies are changing..at least in the software sense.  Programmers are demanding these changes and they are happening.

Comment: What?  Programmers anre not, in general, managers.  The people seeking to fill vacancies do not care about failed applicants - they failed.  No further resources will be spent on them.  Absolutely, no steps would be taken that might introduce any kind of dispute, controversy or, (~~shudder~~), lawyers.

Comment: @MartinJames - I'd also unfortunately rather hear that another candidate filled the role then leaving me in limbo, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314031/didnt-get-the-job-or-did-i-but-in-limbo-what-are-you-guys-doing-to-pro - at least I have a sense of closure from that specific job.  Too many people wait around hoping that one job they wanted they'll get..but currently they won't ever know.

Comment: Wishing will not make it so. Those managers don't care about failed applicants.  They never have, and never will.

Comment: @MartinJames - Again that is your opinion...I happen to care about applicants whether I had the pleasure to bring them on board or even not.  I make sure i reach out to each applicant (via phone..yes I talk to them - personally.  I don't send any canned responses...I have 2-3 minutes a day to do this.) I get on SO careers and any other job site.

Comment: Oh - don't get me wrong - a rejection note should be sent immediately to failed applicants as soon as the positin is filled, but should not require any details.

Comment: @MartinJames - But we aren't even fulfilling that...If it means a rejection note being sent I'm even happy with that...as I mentioned the comments can be made optional.

Comment: Orite:) ..........................

Comment: If you make it optional you can actually collect some stats on how often it is used instead of arguing about made up statistics :)

Comment: @davidism - So you are in favor of never knowing when you have lost out on a position?

Comment: The downvotes contain no information as to why this is downvoted...I mean do you guys like the fact that you are never updated on whether you lost a position or not?  That is baffling...

Comment: I'm in favor of the equivalent of the downvote button, the "reject" button.  But requiring reasons comes with the same issues as requiring them for downvotes, which has been discussed extensively (and very regularly) already.

Comment: I said optional comments...what I am expecting is a standard set of radio buttons that state common reasons and an OPTIONAL textbox if the recruiter or employer want's to elaborate.

Answer (score 11):

As a candidate, I would consider this extremely useful to the point of being almost essential. In fact, before reading this question I simply *assumed* it is currently the case that you get a (automated) notification for a rejected application!

If I apply to five jobs, but would (strongly) prefer one or two of them, and get a offer from one of the "less preferred" jobs, should I take it? Or wait until I get a reply from the preferred jobs?

Or what if I applied to ten positions? Am I still waiting to be reviewed or have I been dismissed for all of them? Do I need to apply for more positions? I find writing cover letters to be the the hardest part of job hunting by far, and sending out applications is a real investment of time.

Right now there is no way to know I was explicitly dismissed or if I'm still "in the queue", so to speak.

I could send a message, but I don't like being pushy.

I don't need a special comment (although that would of course be appreciated). Just a brief generic notification in the order of:

> The employer has looked at your application, and decide it wasn't a good fit. Sorry :-( Better luck next time!

would do the job fine! This would require zero extra effort on the employers side.

Comment: Thank you...someone who understands...and states exactly what I am trying to state in a much better tone.

Comment: @JonH FYI, I think that the problem was that your original question didn't make it very clear that *no* notification *at all* is being sent, and seemed to request that a custom message be made mandatory...

Answer (score 3):

I don't use the Careers site, so I don't know if it already works this way (it sounds like it doesn't) but this can be tied to an action the employers have to do anyway: take down the job posting. There only needs to be three options when removing a job ad:

1. Position was filled
2. Position was removed
3. Position to be re-posted

If job postings just expire, as opposed to being manually taken down, the employer can set a default reason to be sent out to candidates. Minimal extra effort on the employer's part and candidates know they aren't still in the running with that company.

Requiring anything more than that is like requiring a comment for down votes. You're going to get a lot of *"aldkfjaso I have to type something here: apodijaq"* or as Martin said, *'a candidate applied who was better suited to the role'*.

But I don't have any skin in the game, so this is just a suggestion of something I think might work. It won't affect me either way.

Comment: This is a good path I believe.